# Reload docker logging configuration without daemon restart

Tags: docker, logging, kubernetes

I have some up & running kubernetes cluster which potentially can produce a lot of logs.
Kubernetes is running on top of docker so I think I need to [configure dockerd to rollout logs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/).

I found some settings for logging driver for dockerd:

```
{
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "10k",
    "max-file": "2"
  }
}
```

In case of docker service restart the changes are successfully applied.

```
du /var/lib/docker/containers/container_hash/container_hash* -h
```

shows log files splitted on chunks by appropriate size.

But I don't want to restart the daemon, so tried to reload configuration with:

```
sudo kill -SIGHUP $(pidof dockerd)
```

In syslog I found:

```
Mar 12 15:38:16 kso-gl dockerd[5331]: time="2018-03-12T15:38:16.446894155+02:00" level=info msg="Got signal to reload configuration, reloading fr
om: /etc/docker/daemon.json"
```

So, I assume the configuration was reloaded. Unfortunately it had no effect. Even for new containers.
Looks like subsystem related to logging drivers ignores configuration reload.

Comment: maybe you can specific logging parameters when you're running container by
--log-opt max-size=10m --log-opt max-file=10

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sadly it appears the configuration reload SIGHUP feature does not support all configuration options.

The docs at https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#miscellaneous-options (See the "CONFIGURATION RELOAD BEHAVIOR" section) tell us the only supported configuration options which can be reloaded in this way are:

```
The list of currently supported options that can be reconfigured is this:

debug: it changes the daemon to debug mode when set to true.
cluster-store: it reloads the discovery store with the new address.
cluster-store-opts: it uses the new options to reload the discovery store.
cluster-advertise: it modifies the address advertised after reloading.
labels: it replaces the daemon labels with a new set of labels.
live-restore: Enables keeping containers alive during daemon downtime.
max-concurrent-downloads: it updates the max concurrent downloads for each pull.
max-concurrent-uploads: it updates the max concurrent uploads for each push.
default-runtime: it updates the runtime to be used if not is specified at container creation. It defaults to “default” which is the runtime shipped with the official docker packages.
runtimes: it updates the list of available OCI runtimes that can be used to run containers
authorization-plugin: specifies the authorization plugins to use.
allow-nondistributable-artifacts: Replaces the set of registries to which the daemon will push nondistributable artifacts with a new set of registries.
insecure-registries: it replaces the daemon insecure registries with a new set of insecure registries. If some existing insecure registries in daemon’s configuration are not in newly reloaded insecure resgitries, these existing ones will be removed from daemon’s config.
registry-mirrors: it replaces the daemon registry mirrors with a new set of registry mirrors. If some existing registry mirrors in daemon’s configuration are not in newly reloaded registry mirrors, these existing ones will be removed from daemon’s config.
```

Which, as you can see, does not include the `log-driver` or `log-opts` configuration parameters.

I'm not aware of a way to reload the logging configuration without a restart, at this time.

Comment: It seems a possible solution if you just don't want to restart your containers would be:
1. change "live-restore" option with the live config reload using SIGHUP.
2. change the log options
3. restart the docker daemon

I haven't tested this, but it seems like it could work - at

Comment: Thanks @Adriaan, however, the whole point is to avoid restarting the docker daemon.

Comment: For me the point is to not restart all of the containers being managed by the docker daemon - and this solution would keep all of the containers running while the daemon restarts and reloads the configuration. I know that strictly speaking he asked for not restarting the daemon, but in practice the most probable reason for that would be not wanting to restart the containers..

Comment: The Docker live-restore option may be of help for next time: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/live-restore/

Comment: Seems this is still the case in 2023. Sad